# Why MSVC linker chooses kernel32.lib function over my static library one on 64 bit build but not 32

Tags: linker, visual-studio-2022

Just spent half a day debugging this - grr. I know how to fix it but was surprised by the behavior. Wondered if there is a logical explanation

Minimal repro

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef enum {
    FILETYPE_UNKNOWN = -1,      /* Unknown file type */
} FILETYPE;

FILETYPE GetFileType(const char* name);
int main()
{
    FILETYPE x = GetFileType("xx");
    printf("return value is %d\n", x);
}
```

static library with one file

```
typedef enum {
    FILETYPE_UNKNOWN = -1,      /* Unknown file type */
} FILETYPE;

FILETYPE GetFileType(const char* name) {
    return     FILETYPE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Compiled as C code (important)

Then linked like this (32)

```
/OUT:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\StaticLib1.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.iobj" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

this (64)

```
/OUT:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\StaticLib1.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\work\endlines\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.iobj" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Note that the static library is after kernel32.lib.
Those 2 lines are identical except for the paths and the /MACHINE setting

When compiled for 32 bit windows it links my GetFileType

```
return value is -1
```

When compiled for 64 bit windows it links kernel32.lib GetFileType

```
return value is 0
```

vs 2022

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.34.31937.0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.34.31937 for x64
```

Answer (score 0):

well this was a long interesting journey

The c code did not include windows.h (its portable code only using c standard stuff, no windows API calls)

If it had done then the function call declraration would be decorated like this

```
WINBASEAPI
DWORD
WINAPI
GetFileType(
    _In_ HANDLE hFile
    );
```

And the actual symbol emitted would be

```
__imp__GetFileType
```

on x64

```
__imp__GetFileType@4
```

but x32

the point is that the entry point names in the 64 bit version of kernel32.lib (all windows system libraries) are not mangled at all. The entry point is actually called GetFileType. But on the 32 bit version its really called GetFileType@4.

Anyway the lesson here is - dont accidentally name your function in your c code the same as a Win32 API call.